# Which Web technologies allow for the development of static user interface/presentation layers

Tags: java, web-services, spring, nexus

I have a Spring-WS web service that runs on a Jboss application server. I also have a Spring-MVC application running on a separate server running Jboss 7. The Spring-MVC application is used mainly for the user interface. The Spring-WS application contains all the services for the business logic.

The standard approach to use the components we have would be in the following order:

```
Client Browser ---(HTTP Request)---> Spring MVC ----(SOAP Request)-----> Spring-WS
Client Browser <---(HTTP Request)--- Spring MVC <----(SOAP Response)<----- Spring-WS
```

There is a requirement to change some of the requests coming from the Client Browser to go direct to the Web Services instead of via the Spring MVC application. The Spring MVC application will be used to load the initial presentation screens but the actions that involve any updates/writes will be going through the Spring-WS process.

To achieve this, we have a bespoke process which runs on the same machine as the client browser that traps all HTTP requests. Its purpose is to convert the request to a SOAP message and the response to a HTTP response. The path is shown below:

Initial Request (Retrieve presentation/user interface)

```
Client Browser ---(HTTP Request)---> Spring MVC
```

Subsequent requests

```
Client Browser ---(Http Request) ----> SOAP Converter (Local process) ------> (SOAP Request) ----> Spring-WS
Client Browser <---(Http Request) ---- SOAP Converter (Local process) <------ (SOAP Request) <---- Spring-WS
```

There are two paths that happen in the above scenario. The initial request to display the pages on the screen will be a request to the Spring-MVC process. Any subsequent requests that involve changing the data will be via the path shown above.

The problem that i have now is that all responses from Spring-WS (the webservice) are in XML format. This means that when the request comes from the browser, the data will have to come from the web service but the pages will need to be refreshed from the Spring-MVC application. This somehow feels a bit wrong as each request will involve to calls. One to get the data and one to get the presentation data.

To overcome this, i would like to implement the Spring-MVC layer using a technique where i only need to make one initial request. This means that the user interface will rendered on the screen. All subsequent requests to the Spring-WS service should not result in the browser to be rendered other than refreshing the data.

I am interested in knowing what kind of technologies i can use to achieve this. One way of doing this is by using Applets but this has been ruled out for security reasons. I have seen several websites which work exactly the way i have described above. i.e. the page never refreshes. A very good example is the Sonatype Nexus Maven repository manager user interface shown below:

[image: http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/figs/web/repository-manager_public-interface.png]

It runs in a web browser and when the Nexus user interface loads on the browser, it is almost like a Swing type application. (Any one know what technology Nexus use for the user interface?)

I guess my question is which Web based user interface technologies (preferably open source) can i use which has a swing type look and feel but is not Swing and requires minimal requests to the server to refresh the screens?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nexus' interface is built using [Sencha GXT3](http://www.sencha.com/products/gxt/download/), which now also contains ExtJS.

Have a look at the GXT API: it contains a lot of web components which knows how to update their own state without doing the full request/response cycle (using Ajax), which is what you seem to be trying to get away from.

Comment: Thanks - That looks interesting. I am looking into it now.